# Get запрос срабатывает дважды. Почему?

Tags: java, spring, mvc, get

Пытаюсь отправить Get запрос на метод update в controller, но он срабатывает дважды. Вот URL запроса `localhost:8080/currency/USD/EUR`:

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/currency")
public class CurrencyController {
    private CurrencyService currencyService;

    @Autowired
    public CurrencyController(CurrencyService currencyService) {
        this.currencyService = currencyService;
    }

    ///currency/RUB/EUR пример запросса 1EUR=84RUB
    @GetMapping("/{symbols}/{base}")
    public ResponseEntity update(@PathVariable String symbols, @PathVariable String base) {
        log.warn(currencyService.update(symbols, base).toString());
        return currencyService.update(symbols, base);
    }
}
```

**Service method update**

```java
public ResponseEntity update(@NonNull String symbols, @NonNull String base) {
    log.warn("OKAY Start!");
    Long id = currencyRepository.findMaxId() + 1;
    Currency currencyLoadDate = new Currency();
    String apiRequest = API.concat("?symbols=").concat(symbols).concat("&base=").concat(base);
    AnswerLatestData answerLatestData = restTemplate.getForEntity(apiRequest, AnswerLatestData.class).getBody();
    Date date = answerLatestData.getDate();
    Double value = Objects.isNull(answerLatestData.getRates().getRub())
            ? Objects.isNull(answerLatestData.getRates().getEur())
            ? answerLatestData.getRates().getUsd()
            : answerLatestData.getRates().getEur()
            : answerLatestData.getRates().getRub();
    currencyLoadDate.setId(id);
    currencyLoadDate.setQuotedTitleCurrency(symbols);
    currencyLoadDate.setBasicTitleCurrency(base);
    currencyLoadDate.setDate(date);
    currencyLoadDate.setValue(value);
    log.warn("HELLO");
    if (!Objects.isNull(currencyRepository.findByDateAndBasicTitleCurrencyAndQuotedTitleCurrency(date, base, symbols))) {
        log.warn("TRUE");
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    } else {
        log.warn("FALSE");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(currencyRepository.save(currencyLoadDate));
    }
}
```

**Output log**

```
2020-08-03 18:05:55.502  WARN 18093 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] r.k.s.currency.service.CurrencyService   : OKAY Start!

2020-08-03 18:05:56.608  WARN 18093 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] r.k.s.currency.service.CurrencyService   : HELLO

2020-08-03 18:05:56.745  WARN 18093 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] r.k.s.currency.service.CurrencyService   : TRUE

2020-08-03 18:05:56.746  WARN 18093 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] r.k.s.c.controller.CurrencyController    : <404 NOT_FOUND Not Found,[]>

2020-08-03 18:05:56.746  WARN 18093 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] r.k.s.currency.service.CurrencyService   : OKAY Start!

2020-08-03 18:05:56.794  WARN 18093 --- [        s0-io-3] c.d.o.d.i.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler     : Query '[0 values] select MAX(id) FROM currency ALLOW FILTERING' generated server side warning(s): Aggregation query used without partition key

2020-08-03 18:05:56.876  WARN 18093 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] r.k.s.currency.service.CurrencyService   : HELLO

2020-08-03 18:05:56.929  WARN 18093 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] r.k.s.currency.service.CurrencyService   : TRUE*
```

Comment: Вы два раза вызываете `currencyService.update(symbols, base)`. Сохраните результат вызова в переменную и используйте её вместо повторного вызова.

Comment: Я же в логе тоже вызываю метод. Внимательность уровень 80. Спасибо!